# Android: Examples web like Cocoacontrols in iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, code-snippets

Anyone knows a web of Android samples, just like cocoacontrols for iPhone? I've searched but I don't find any similar.

Thanks!

Comment: what is cocoacontrols? post some info or a picture or something if you can

Comment: Not a programming question and hence not suitable for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Sorry, I realize you probably mean community solutions. Try this:
http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid

These guys specialize just in components:
http://www.openintents.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

Check out GreenDroid

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid